# RSYNC exclude directory from destination path

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

I want to exclude folders which are already on a remote server (i.e. `test/xyz`) and I want to run `rsync` from my source server where I have `test1/xyz` folder so I don't want to overwrite `xyz` folder on remote side.

Also I want to update the files if there any files deleted/added on source server that will be deleted/added on the remote server, but excluding the `test/xyz` folder.

I have tried below command to exclude the remote directory but it copies excluded directory and files on remote directory.

```
rsync -ave ssh --exclude=remotedirectory root@IPADDRESS:remotepath --delete sourcepath
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways.

1. Just `--exclude=dir` and there is no difference if it's local or remote, as you anyway do not want to sync it.
2. Use `--rsync-path='rsync --exclude=dir'` and remote rsync will be executed with that exclude option.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude=/xyz/ sourcepath/ root@IPADDRESS:remotepath/
```

That will exclude "xyz" when it occurs in the root of "sourcepath", *and* is a directory (the trailing "/" ensures that).

The trailing slashes on the source and destination directories are important. Without that the *second* rsync run would create a new folder "remotepath/sourcepath", which is probably not what you want.

Also, you had the source and destination parameters the wrong way around, according to you description (but the confusion could be mine).